# How to share data with row bases access control?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm try to share data with row bases access control with this policy:

```
create or replace row access policy security.agency_policy as (agency_name varchar) returns boolean ->
  'AGENCY_EXECUTIVE_ROLE' = current_role()
      or exists (
            select 1 from "INSURANCE"."SECURITY"."AGENCY_MANAGER_MAPPING"
              where agency_manager = current_role()
                and agency = agency_name
          )
;
```

the policy it work properly in main account but when shared to data provider and create the new role that use the same name in main account, then query the data it not return anything.

for data provider account:
I'm `GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES on database "INSURANCE" TO ROLE agency_executive_role;`
form this role it should be see all data (because 'AGENCY_EXECUTIVE_ROLE' = current_role()), but result not show anything.

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the USER ACCESS policy in the consumer account.